# 2014 Money Challenge - Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to write an algebraic equation for the following situation where:

when $x$ is $0$; $y=0$

when $x$ is $1$; $y=1$

when $x$ is $2$; $y=3$

when $x$ is $3$; $y=6$

when $x$ is $4$; $y=10 \dots$

I work with 8th grade students and we were looking at 2014 Money Challenge where you deposit money into a jar every week, the amount being related to the number of week of the year.

Answer (score 3):

Considering you are working with 8th grader, you may want to show the result visually (pick two students, Becky with blue dots and Rodney with red dots) as below. I got it from 
http://maybemath.wordpress.com/category/proof-without-words/
[image: Triangle numbers]

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: lol. You are very kind. I wish I could take credit for the answer. Credit really goes to the original author and Google. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider when $x = a$ and when $x = a+1$. What is the difference between $y_a$ and $y_{a+1}$? Then you can take the recursive formula and convert it to a more explicit form.

Answer (score 0):

Through simple observation you can see that these are triangle numbers. Given by the formulae: $$T_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$
It is analogous to factorials in the context of addition. Another way to think about it is adding the first n integers for the nth triangle number. $T_n=1+2+…+n$

In your context on the nth week I am adding n amount of money. Done from the start it becomes the triangle numbers.